# Problem displaying strings

Tags: arrays, user-interface, matlab, matrix

Hey guyz. Can help me on this?

```
if size(cost,1) == 2

       A = (4*Pdt*cost(1,3)*cost(2,3)) + 2*(cost(1,2)*cost(2,3))+(cost(1,3)*cost(2,2));
       B = 2*(cost(2,3)+cost(1,3));
       lambda = num2str(A ./ B);
       set(handles.answer1_staticText,'String', lambda);
       P1 = (lambda - cost(1,2))./(2*cost(1,3));
       P2 = (lambda - cost(2,2))./(2*cost(2,3));
       PT = mat2str(P1 + P2);
       set(handles.answer2_staticText,'String', PT);
       guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

From the coding above, the answer become like this :

```
[11.75 11.25 11.25 11.75 10.75 11.5 12.75 12.75 13]
```

My question is I want to display my answer at the static text box like this:

```
P1 = (%answer for P1)

P2 = (%answer for P2)

P TOTAL = (%answer for PT)
```

Can anyone help me with the coding?

Comment: You need to make sure that the final result is a *scalar*, and not a *matrix*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have converted `lambda` to a string (using `num2str`), and thus, the calculation of `P1` etc will produce unexpected results.

It's better to only convert to string in the display step, so these accidents won't happen.

Try this:

```
if size(cost,1) == 2

       A = (4*Pdt*cost(1,3)*cost(2,3)) + 2*(cost(1,2)*cost(2,3))+(cost(1,3)*cost(2,2));
       B = 2*(cost(2,3)+cost(1,3));
       lambda = A ./ B;
       set(handles.answer1_staticText,'String', num2str(lambda));
       P1 = (lambda - cost(1,2))./(2*cost(1,3));
       P2 = (lambda - cost(2,2))./(2*cost(2,3));
       PT = P1 + P2;
       set(handles.answer2_staticText,'String', num2str(PT));
       guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

Comment: how can i display the answer like this :                  P1 = (%answer for P1)

P2 = (%answer for P2)

P TOTAL = (%answer for PT)